# mySql query intermediate table

Tags: php, mysql

i try to find out if a conversation between two users exist but i can't imagine how to query this in mysql.

My tables are:

```
users
-----
id
name

conversations
-------------
id

conversation_user
-----------------
user_id
conversation_id
```

For example, i have two users and one conversation so in my conversation_user table i have

```
user_id    conversation_id
1          1
2          1
```

How to check if this relationship exist or not?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use join for that:

```
SELECT
    c1.*, c2.*
FROM
    conversation_user c1
INNER JOIN
    conversation_user c2
ON
    c1.conversation_id = c2.conversation_id
WHERE
    c1.user_id != c2.user_id;
```

---

You can take a look at this [SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6e49e/3) that is a bit more detailed. It shows an example of bringing the **name of the users** and one that **filters by conversation**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select c1.user_id as user1, c2.user_id as user2 
from conversation_user c1, conversation_user c2 
where c1.conversation_id = c2.conversation_id and not c1.user_id = c2.user_id
```